# MARIA DB INSERT SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm attempting to run this query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO obras_analisis (concepto, obra, fecha, importe, idcon, af, ordenaf, porcentaje) 
(SELECT '(CD) COSTO DIRECTO',obra, now(), sum(importe) foo, idcon,1, 1, 100 FROM obras_analisis
     WHERE obra=2 
     group by idcon 
) as ob2
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE obras_analisis.importe=ob2.foo
;
```

But, get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'as ob2  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE obras_analisis.importe=ob2.foo'
> at line 5

Answer (score 1):

You can't give an alias to the `SELECT` query in `INSERT`. Use `VALUES(columnname)`  to get the value that would have been inserted into that column.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO obras_analisis (concepto, obra, fecha, importe, idcon, af, ordenaf, porcentaje) 
(SELECT '(CD) COSTO DIRECTO',obra, now(), sum(importe) foo, idcon,1, 1, 100 FROM obras_analisis
     WHERE obra=2 
     group by idcon 
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE importe = VALUES(importe)
;
```